# How to add a comment to an attached property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

Is there any way to add a comment to an attached property. Something that will show up to the end user? I tried the standard triple slash and added a summary to no avail.

Comment: Are you talking about like [localization.comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.localization.comments(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Show us how you did it.

Comment: The 'end user' is the developer or the customer?